# (C#) What are the D1-9 and F17-24 keys and is there a way to use them with sendkeys?

Tags: c#

This is the code I use to send a key code

```
using System.IO.Ports;
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Collections;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows.Forms;


namespace Arduino3
{
    internal static class Program { 

        //This is just a way to communicate with an Arduino
        static SerialPort _serialPort;
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            _serialPort = new SerialPort();
            _serialPort.PortName = "COM5";//Set your board COM
            _serialPort.BaudRate = 9600;
            _serialPort.Open();
                 
            while (true)
            {
                string a = _serialPort.ReadExisting();
                Console.WriteLine(a);
                if(a == "test")
                {
                    SendKey();
                }
                Thread.Sleep(500);
            }
        }

        //This is one way I tried to send keys 
        private static void SendKey()
        {
            [DllImport("User32.dll")]
            static extern int SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr point);

            var p = Process.GetProcessesByName("Discord").LastOrDefault();
            var pointer = p.Handle;

            SetForegroundWindow(pointer);
            SendKeys.SendWait("F13");//F13,14,15,16
            SendKeys.Flush();

        }



        
    
    }
}
```

I can send keys like F13, F14, F15, F16, but F17 to F24 doesn't work.

And for keys D0-D9 I know nothing about and couldn't find much to answer my questions.

I tried using it like {F17},{D0} but it outputs an error saying "Keyword "D0" is not valid".

[Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.keys?view=windowsdesktop-6.0)

Comment: From the [reference source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/SendKeys.cs,38), you see that the table of special keys goes up to F16, and there's no mention of the D0 through D9 keys. Not sure where you got those D keys from. They appear to have come from your imagination.

Comment: If you click the only link I posted and scroll down a little you will se in the microsoft docs the D keys I reffer to and a little bit lower there will be the F17-F24 keys. And thats why I asked about them because I am not sure what their purpose is.

Comment: D0 through D9 are the digits 0 through 9. For SendKeys you just use `"0"` to send the digit 0. The enum calls them "D0" because an enum value name must begin with a letter or underscore.